# How to cross domain get data from Google Search

Tags: php, javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to get data from Google Search, "cross-domainly". I come up with PHP, but I don't want to use it. I want to get the data directly using JavaScript. But how? JSONP? or other?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: You probably would like to use Google's custom search API, see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978242/how-to-load-googles-custom-search-enginecse-js-apis-after-page-loads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google search API just by ajax,like jQuery.get().because  Google's javascript API get around the cross-domain security in AJAX

Comment: I am now using YQL to fetch data from other domains (you probably realized this question is quite old). Anyway, I will accept your answer because you are the only person who answered in the past year. ;)

Comment: one week ago I called google custom search API by ajax,so i want to konw how dose google javascript api get around cross-domain.not jsonp,what is...i search in stack,then i see you question.

Comment: I think the used the `<script>` tag to avoid the same origin policy because it is the only way to do it.