# Initialising Google Earth Plugin after page load leads to empty page

Tags: google-api, google-earth-plugin, google-loader

I am building a page which relies on the Google Earth plugin. The page is built using require.js and backbone. I want to initialise the Google Earth plugin when a given part of the page is navigated to (e.g. a particular backbone route is triggered).

However, if the google earth plugin is initialised (via `google.load('earth', '1');`) after the page load then the contents of the page is replaced with the generated script tag - e.g.:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/uds/?file=earth&amp;v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/uds/api/earth/1.1/109c7b2bae7fe6cc34ea875176165d81/default.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the page disappears.

Is there a way to initialise the plugin after page load or do I need to resort to some code in the HEAD to initialise things and then only call `google.earth.createInstance` when I'm ready to display it?

Answer (score 0):

And just after posting I finally find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978242/how-to-load-googles-custom-search-enginecse-js-apis-after-page-loads#answer-7015191):

```
google.load(
    'earth',
    '1',
    {
        'callback': function()
        {
            // what was in the google.setOnLoadCallback 
            // in the GE plugin examples 
        }
    }
);
```

(assuming you already included the `<script>` tag pointing to https://www.google.com/jsapi ). Passing in a callback as part of the third parameter to `google.load` apparently stops it from writing script tags to your document and overwriting whatever else was there!